# Input теряет focus при вводе одного символа (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть например массив data который через map() создаёт разметку в приложении на React.

```
 data: [
          {
            id: 1,
            firstName: "Ксения",
            middleName: "Сергеевна",
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            firstName: "Константин",
            middleName: "Сергеевич",
          },
        ];
```

Вот есть 2 input:

```
      <input
        type="text"
        value={firstName}
        name="firstName"
        onChange={(event) => changeData(event)}
      />

      <input
        type="text"
        value={middleName}
        name="middleName"
        onChange={(event) => changeData(event)}
      />
```

Хочу изменить состояние в одном из input значения которых соответствуют значениям из объектов в массиве.

```
const changeData = (event) => {
  setData(
    data.map((item) =>
      item.id === detailId // Ловит нужный объект в массиве.
        ? { ...item, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }
        : item
    )
  );
};
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при вводе одного любого символа в любой из input он сразу теряет фокус(focus).

Значения в state меняются правильно.
Я так понимаю что при вводе любого символа компонент перерисовывается и поэтому фокус теряется.
Но как это обойти, пока не получается. Спасибо за ответы)

Comment: Кода в вопросе недостаточно для ответа. Почти наверняка ты где-то пересоздаёшь дерево компонентов. или накосячил с key, или в качестве компонента используешь какую-то меняющуюся функцию.

Answer (score 0):

Представлено недостаточно кода, но поделюсь своим решением аналогичной проблемы. У меня инпуты создавались в стрелочной функции:

```
const FirstStage = () => (
<>
      <label htmlFor="courseNameInput">Название курса</label>
      <TextField
        key="courseNameInput"
        variant="filled"
        size="small"
        onChange={(event) => setCourseName(event.target.value)}
        value={courseName}
        name="courseNameInput"
      /> <>...
```

Далее эта функция рендерилась подобным образом:

```
return (
<FirstStage />
)
```

Данная ошибка пропала после того, как начал рендерить следующим образом:

```
return (
    {FirstStage()}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня была точно такая же проблема, в моём случае дело было в том что в функции которая перерисовывала всё дерево создавался рут элемент.

было:

```
    export let rerenderTree = (state) => {
      const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
      root.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </React.StrictMode>
      );
    };
```

стало:

```
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

    export let rerenderTree = (state) => {
      root.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <App  />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </React.StrictMode>
      );
    };
```

---

строка ->

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
```

была вынесена за пердел функции. Это исправило проблему фокуса.

```
введите сюда код
```

Answer (score 0):

Потеря фокуса происходит из-за того, что вы используете map для отрисовки input-ов, точнее из-за того что вы меняете состояние input который находится вне input как компонента. Как лечить? Есть два рецепта:

1. Отказаться от map:

   ```
    export const Component = () => {

    const [firstPerson, setFirstPerson] = useState({
     firstName: "Ксения",
     middleName: "Сергеевна",
    });

    const [secondPerson, setSecondPerson] = useState({
     firstName: "Константин",
     middleName: "Сергеевич",
    });

    return (
     <>
      <input
       type="text"
       value={firstPerson.firstName}
       name="firstName"
       onChange={(event) =>
       setFirstPerson((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        firstName: event.target.value,
       }))
     }
    />

    <input
    type="text"
    value={firstPerson.middleName}
    name="middleName"
    onChange={(event) =>
      setFirstPerson((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        middleName: event.target.value,
      }))
    }
    />

    <input
    type="text"
    value={secondPerson.firstName}
    name="firstName"
    onChange={(event) =>
      setSecondPerson((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        firstName: event.target.value,
      }))
    }
    />

    <input
    type="text"
    value={secondPerson.middleName}
    name="middleName"
    onChange={(event) =>
      setSecondPerson((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        middleName: event.target.value,
      }))
     }
        />
       </>
      );
     };
   ```

2.Сделать отдельный компонент в котором будет свой state и потом уже использовать map:

```
const Field = ({ firstName, middleName }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    firstName,
    middleName,
  });
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={data.firstName}
        name="firstName"
        onChange={(event) =>
        setData((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        firstName: event.target.value,
      }))
    }
  />

  <input
    type="text"
    value={data.middleName}
    name="middleName"
    onChange={(event) =>
      setData((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        middleName: event.target.value,
      }))
    }
      />
    </>
  );
};

export const Component = () => {
  const data = [
    {
  id: 1,
  firstName: "Ксения",
  middleName: "Сергеевна",
    },
    {
  id: 2,
  firstName: "Константин",
  middleName: "Сергеевич",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <>
  {data.map((element) => (
    <Field
      key={element.id}
      firstName={element.firstName}
      middleName={element.middleName}
    />
  ))}
    </>
  );
};
```